# Android AudioRecorder with UI

Tags: android, audio-recording

I want to create an audio recorder I have tried the code I get from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html and it works fine; it records and it plays back what I have said. But right now I want to create an audio recorder with a UI like in recognizerIntent which Google has provided so that you can see or monitor that your voice has been recorded(sorry I can't find a right term but I'm hoping you can understand what I am trying to say). Do you know any tutorial or links that can help me?thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean that you want some feedback that your voice is being picked up? If so, perhaps [this project, Audalyzer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/moonblink/wikis/Audalyzer.wiki) might be a good place to start looking?

Libraries within the package offer you a dB reading, a one and two-dimensional wave form, and an FFT plot.

[image: screen shot]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://moonblink.googlecode.com/files/Audalyzer-1.3-choral.png))</sub>

Comment: yes I have already checked this project and I can say that it's really cool and amazing! but the code seems too complicated for me to understand. So I would like to create maybe a simple one. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler [WaveformControl](https://github.com/newventuresoftware/WaveformControl) you may find easier to understand and modify for your needs.